# Learning java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have an existing code in Java that I would like to write in Java 8.

Could someone provide suggestions of porting this code to Java 8.

```
class Solution {

public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {

    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap();

    if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) return result;

    for (String word: strs) {
        char[] wordArr = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(wordArr);
        String sortedWord = new String(wordArr);
        if (map.containsKey(sortedWord)) {
            List<String> list = map.get(sortedWord); 
            list.add(word);
            map.put(sortedWord, list);
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(word);
            map.put(sortedWord, list);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList(map.values());
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**  - I have used getOrDefault()

```
class Solution {

    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {

        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList();

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap();

        if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) return result;

        for (String word: strs) {
            char[] wordArr = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(wordArr);
            String sortedWord = new String(wordArr);
            List<String> list = map.getOrDefault(sortedWord, new ArrayList());
            list.add(word);
            map.put(sortedWord, list);
        }
        return new ArrayList(map.values());
    }
}
```

Any other way ?

Comment: When you say “*write in Java 8*”, are you mostly looking to use streams?

Comment: ......... and if so, please show your attempt

Comment: I think this can be made concise

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sure I'll post my attempt

Comment: The above code is valid Java 8 code.

Comment: I think I can make the code in if and else block concise

Comment: Look at the `Map.computeIfAbsent` method.

Comment: `getOrDefault` is the wrong choice here. Use `computeIfAbsent`, as in `map.computeIfAbsent(sortedWord, k -> new ArrayList()).add(word)`

Comment: This question is innately a poor fit for our format -- it's a request for improvements to already-working code (permitted on [codereview.se], disallowed here) rather than a narrow question about a specific problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. But this post has helped me understand a concept well. Just going through Java8 concepts would be fine. But the real learning is by implementing it in a problem. This discussion really helped me with that. Is stackexchange a good place for similar posts ?

Comment: [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) is a good place to start in figuring out which of the two sites is a better fit for a given question. Questions that aren't topical on either may also be a fit for Programmers -- see [What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-software-engineering-previously-known-as-programmers-a-guide-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the best solution I could come up with using streams:

```java
public class Solution {
    private static String sortString(String str) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        return new String(chars);
    }

    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        if (strs == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(strs)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Solution::sortString))
                .values());
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

Starting simple, we create a stream from the array `strs` using the utility method [`Arrays.stream(array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-):

```java
Arrays.stream(strs);
```

The [`Stream#collect(collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method takes a stream and converts it into a standard collection type (`Map`, `List`, etc.):

```java
Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(...);
```

In this instance, we’re going to use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). This collector sorts your stream into ‘bins’, with the bin label specified by the result of passing each value through the `classifier` lambda function. The return type is a `Map<K, List<V>>` (where `K` is the label type and `V` is whatever type we’re streaming) - the same shape you used for your `map` variable:

```java
Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...));
```

But what function do we pass `.groupingBy()`? Since you’re looking to group by the sorted string, we need a function which will create a sorted string from a regular one. We’re going to use your existing function for this:

```java
Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> {
                char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(chars);
                return new String(chars);
        }));
```

<s>In the interest of being streamy though, we replace that function with *another* stream*:</s> (*It turns out `char`s don’t stream nicely*)

In the interest of neatness, I’ve refactored the lambda function into a static method on your class:

```java
private static String sortString(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

```java
Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> {
                return Solution.sortString(str);
        }));
```

Since we’re making a single call to a function which takes only one parameter, we can use a method reference instead of the lambda function:

```java
Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Solution::sortString));
```

The rest is very similar to your existing code. Using [`Map#values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) to strip the keys from the dataset, then wrapping the resulting `Collection` in an `ArrayList`:

```java
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Solution::sortString))
        .values());
```

Comment: Don't use raw type

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you please provide a short explanation

Comment: @MTCoster you're explaining something that is already in the OP's code. Also prefer give explanation by editing your post for the next people that will come here

Comment: @MTCoster Looks like there's a compilation issue in the code. In the inner stream

Arrays.stream(str.toCharArray())

Comment: @user3451476 I wrote this solution without my IDE - didn’t realise `char`s don’t stream nicely! Fixed now

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially looking for the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector:

```
List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {       
    if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) 
         return new ArrayList<>();

    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(strs)
            .collect(groupingBy(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(joining())))
            .values());
}
```

First, we create a Stream upon invoking `Arrays.stream(strs)` which then enables us to perform a reduction operation using `collect`, this method consumes a Collector where this Collector is a `groupingBy`.

This overload of the `groupingBy` collector produces a `Map<K, List<T>>` where keys are the values resulting from applying the classification function to the input elements (i.e. `Arrays.stream(s.split("")).sorted().collect(joining())`), and whose corresponding values are Lists containing the input elements which map to the associated key under the classification function.

Finally, we call `values()` to retrieve a `Collection<List<String>>` and pass this to the `ArrayList` constructor and return.

Reading you might find interesting:

- [Collectors documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)
- [Streams documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)
- [Introduction to Java 8 Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction)
- [Java 8: An Introduction to Streams](https://www.gravytrain.co.uk/blog/java-8-introduction-streams/)

Comment: Some explanations should be interesting, as the principal OP's problem was that he does not know the Java 8 Streams features

Comment: `s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("")).sorted().collect(joining())` is quiet heavy for the intended purpose. Since the actual key type does not matter here (i.e. doesn’t need to be a `String`), you can use `s -> IntBuffer.wrap(s.chars().sorted().toArray())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Aomine is good, but it is possible to rewrite shorter:

```
return strs == null? Collection.emptyList() : new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(strs)
        .collect(groupingBy(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
                .sorted()
                .collect(joining())))
        .values());
```

Comment: Some explanations should be interesting, as the principal OP's problem was that he does not know the Java 8 Streams features

Answer (score 1):

[This answer provides a java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687559/learning-java-8/53687632#53687632) solution which personally I would proceed with. As for your current implementation, you're quite close but `computeIfAbsent` would be the better approach to proceed with:

```
List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String word : strs) {
            char[] wordArr = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(wordArr);
            map.computeIfAbsent(new String(wordArr), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(word);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

I am pretty sure you know what most of the code does so I'll only explain the [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) part above by quoting most of the documentation as it's the best explanation.

> if the specified key (`new String(wordArr)`) is not already associated
>   with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value
>   using the given mapping function (`k -> new ArrayList<>()`) and enters
>   it into this map unless null.

next time we attempt to add a key that is already present in the map, the existing list associated with the specified key is returned and we add the word into it with `.add(word)` above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Streams` refer to the other answers, if you want to know how yo use `Map` operation to simplify your if/else here it is :

It the `key` is not in the `map`, add it with an `empty list`, then get that `list` and `add` the `word` :

```
for (String word : strs) {
    char[] wordArr = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(wordArr);
    String sortedWord = new String(wordArr);

    map.putIfAbsent(sortedWord, new ArrayList<>());
    map.get(sortedWord).add(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Optional and streams and some static imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static java.util.Optional.of;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.EMPTY;

    public class Solution {

        public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {

            Collection<List<String>> collection = of(asList(strs))
                            .orElse(emptyList())
                            .stream()
                            .collect(groupingBy(word -> stream(word.split(EMPTY))
                                            .sorted()
                                            .collect(joining())))
                            .values();
            return new ArrayList<>(collection);
        }
    }
```